# Проверка сессии в каждом руте

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть небольшой сайт на Flask. На некоторых рутах я хочу проверять, активна ли сессия которая несет в себе `cookie` и введенные пользователем данные. Как только ко мне пришла эта идея,я сделал следующую функцию:

```
def check_for_main_sess():
    if flask.session.get('user_data') is None:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('authorize'))
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))
```

Но,после прохода даже через `return`, она не перенаправляла на нужную страницу,а просто проходила мимо. Тогда я сделал декоратор похожего вида:

```
def check_main_sess(func):
    def check_main_sess_inner():
        if flask.session.get('user_data') is None:
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('authorize'))
        return func()
    return check_main_sess_inner
```

К сожалению,он тоже не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Где и как вы используете эти функции? Как проявляется «не работает»? Вставленный в функцию print печатает или не печатает?

Comment: @andreymal Ни одна конструкция выше никак не влияет на работу. В случае с первой,он проходит через каждую строчку и идет дальше, откуда она была вызвана. Я использую VS code,и поэтому могу посмотреть что происходит построчно, но, в декоратор он не заходит вообще.

Comment: А как именно вы декоратор используете-то?

Comment: @andreymal выше функции ставлю <собачка>check_main_sess

Comment: Выше функции где конкретно? Весьма вероятно, что там у вас уже есть другие декораторы — порядок имеет значение

Comment: @andreymal я пробовал и выше объявления рута,и самым первым

Comment: Ваши комментарии какие-то размытые и непонятные, приведите [mcve] в виде кода Flask-приложения с подключенным, но не работающим декоратором (или иной функцией, если есть другие варианты)

Comment: @andreymal я решил свою проблему исправив пару строк в декораторе выше, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После исправления функции декоратора `check_main_sess_inner`, при выходи из if'a должна возвращать `flask.redirect(flask.url_for('home'))`